# Exceed 3 hours timeout Automation Runbook Azure

Tags: azure, process, automation, azure-sql-database, runbook

Hello guys,

I have a runbook to launch but it takes more than 3 hours to run (process of partitions) and so, it stops before being complete. I wanted to know if there is a way to exceed the 3 hours limitation. I've heared about hybrid runbooks but I'm not sure how it could solve my problem. Do you know if there is other solutions ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which type of runbook are you using? Powershell, Powershell Workflow, etc.? I am running into this same issue using a Powershell Workflow runbook and there doesn't seem to be a clear alternative. How did you eventually solve this issue?

Comment: The PowerShell runbook, and at the moment it is still unsolved... I had to split my process in multiple runbooks unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to Azure Automation, you can use **Checkpoints**:

> Azure Automation has a feature called “fairshare”, where any runbook
>   that runs for 3 hours is unloaded to allow other runbooks to run. 
>   Eventually, the unloaded runbook will be reloaded, and when it is it
>   will resume execution from the last checkpoint taken in the runbook. 
>   Thus, in order to guarantee that the runbook will eventually complete,
>   you must add checkpoints at intervals that run for less than 3 hours.

[Source.](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-automation-reliable-fault-tolerant-runbook-execution-using-checkpoints/)

Here is an [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-automation-reliable-fault-tolerant-runbook-execution-using-checkpoints/):

Answer (score 0):

no. there are none, that is if you want Azure Automation. Your options are:

1. Web Jobs
2. Azure Functions (NOT consumption plan)
3. Hybrid workers
4. services\scripts\schedules on your own vms
5. Azure Batch
6. Possibly Azure Data Factory, depending on what you are doing

probably something else.