# Azure Runbook Authentication failed

Tags: azure

I have created Azure run books under and Azure Automation account to process a large Azure Analysis services Tabular model.

When I attempt a full Tabular model process via PowerShell it times out at just after an hour of runtime.

Start: 8:47:50 AM
End:   9:48:25 AM

### ***Command Start***

Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -server "asazure://---" -DatabaseName "---" -RefreshType Full
***Command End***

***Error Start***
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Timeout expired. The timeout

period elapsed prior to completion of the operation.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

Technical Details:

RootActivityId: ---

Date (UTC): ---

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

'.

At line:3 char:1

- Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -server "asazure://--- ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (---:String) [Invoke-ProcessASDatabase],
  ```

OperationException

```
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessASDatabase
```

***Error End***

I then broke the process down to the partition level.  The process partitions run successfully for about an hour as well processing over 100 partitions but then start getting authentication errors.

How can I get a full Tabular model process completed running under an Azure runbook?

Start: 8:59:50 PM
End:   10:06:28 PM

### ***Command Start***

Invoke-ProcessPartition -PartitionName "2018_Q4" -TableName "FACT_AR" -server "asazure://---" -Database "---" -RefreshType Full
***Command End***

***Error Start***
Invoke-ProcessPartition : Authentication failed.

Technical Details:

RootActivityId: ---

Date (UTC): ---

At line:104 char:1

- Invoke-ProcessPartition -PartitionName "2018_Q4" -TableName "FACT_AR ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ProcessPartition], ConnectionException

  + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
  ```

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessPartition
***Error End***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the credential was somehow corrupted.  Dropped the credential and re-created it and the job worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Your issue looks similar to this -> [Exceed 3 hours timeout Automation Runbook Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264868/exceed-3-hours-timeout-automation-runbook-azure). Please check it if the answers given in there helps to resolve your issue.

Also you may read about fair share from below Microsoft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#fair-share

Hope this helps!!